# Vaadin 7 Validation (BeanValidator and setrequired)

Tags: vaadin, validation, bean-validation

Hi I have just started Vaadin 7 and have got the `BeanValidator` working. But, I have some issues. The code I am using is the following:

```
BeanItem<RegisterBean> item = new BeanItem<RegisterBean>(new RegisterBean());
final FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(item);
final TextField email = new TextField("email");
email.addValidator(new BeanValidator(RegisterBean.class, "email"));
```

The validates fine using the BeanValidator. With the `@NotNull` tag I am able to validate for Null values as well. However, I would like to give the user visual clues that the field in the form can't be left blank. For this, I used:

```
email.setRequired(true);
```

However, after adding the `setRequired` the BeanValidation for the form no longer works?

Is this a limitation?
How do I get around it?

Comment: For string fields that should not be left blank please use `@NotEmpty` annotation also on the intended bean field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably rely on the bean validation itself and use the fieldgroup.

My model looks as follows:

```java
@NotNull(message="Please enter a valid email address.")
@Email(message="Please enter a valid email address.")
@Size(min = 3, max = 255, message="Please enter a valid email address.")
@Column(name="P_EMAIL", nullable=true, length=255)
private String email;
```

In your view do either buildAndBind

```java
Field<?> email = binder.buildAndBind("email");
```

Or use the annotation `@PropertyId("email")` in your field declaration. The rest is magic.

Instead of `FieldGroup`use `BeanFieldGroup`.

A problem will be that validation is made preliminary. So install the validators on click. More to that topic can be found here: http://morevaadin.com/content/bean-validation-and-vaadin-comprehensive-example/

Comment: Thanks. That actually is a very good explanation. Could you please elaborate a bit on the use of @column tag? Why is that useful? Also, what would be advantage of using a beanfieldgroup over fieldgroup. The other thing that I am struggling with is how do I then use the sql container to add,update and delete data once the bean validation has fake place.

Comment: I just copied my code. The [@Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation is a JPA-Annotation. BeanFieldGroup binds automatically to your Bean and enables you to use Bean Validation Annotations, thus you don't have add Validators by your self in the view and have all your validation configuration on the model (clear separation of concerns). For CRUD operations you should use a JPA container if you are using JPA and you should (Try the official AGPL version https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/1066517).

Answer (score 1):

To complete the example above, using a BeanFieldGroup, as it got validators, you can use the setValidationVisible method of an AbstractField to turn off preliminary validation, then to turn on in a blurListener and in the buttons clickListeners.

```
AbstractTextField cName = binder.buildAndBind("Name","name", AbstractTextField.class); 
cName.setNullRepresentation("");
cName.setValidationVisible(false);
cName.addBlurListener(new MyBlurListener(cName)); //<-- turn on setValidationVisible there

myButton.addClickListener(event -> {
   try {
       cName.setValidationVisible(true);
       binder.commit();
   } catch (CommitException e){
       Notification.show("Sending error");
   }
});
```